# How do i send request at specific ms in python

Tags: python, time, python-requests

Hello i am trying to send a request to a url at a specific time i wrote this

```
import datetime
import time
from threading import Timer
import requests


def job():
    requests.get('https://www.weather.org')
    print(datetime.datetime.now())


x=datetime.datetime.today()
y = x.replace(day=x.day, hour=21, minute=1, second=59, microsecond=10)
delta_t=y-x
secs = delta_t.seconds+1
Timer(secs,job).start()
```

However when i run it prints`2022-03-30 21:02:00.282179` when it is supposed to print 10ms after any answers on why this is happening?

Comment: It takes some time to send the request and print the time. Is that what you mean?